# prev() not working in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button and on the click of it, I want to have the value of product_id which is its sibling but following code isn't working. It is giving me undefined. [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/weyowatebu/edit?html,console,output) Html is mostly fixed i can't give any classes

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>prev demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="commerce-add-to-cart commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-3" action="/drupal_commerce/" method="post" id="commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-3" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-WLgRLYXPHDHNkH-vTSrERT4DGaqutn88pAlta_eJNig">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="UhnJe2M-N6lxx2LdqBvWm6EUbB7gD0Uv3r3OaTc_s1Q">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_3">
    <div id="edit-line-item-fields--2" class="form-wrapper"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input class="button01 form-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit--3" name="op" value="Add to cart">
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  $('.commerce-add-to-cart input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
console.log($(this).prev('input[name=product_id]').val())
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to use `prevAll` as prev will just get the immediately previous sibling (which in this case is the div)

Comment: @Pete Thanks, It is working.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)